# How to run legacy OpenGL application on modern Windows

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gpu, opengl, emulator

I want to run an OpenGL application from around 2011 on modern Windows 10 (64-bit), but can't really figure out how to do it. The application in problem is a research demo [Proland](https://proland.inrialpes.fr/download.html).

The problem is that when I try to launch the application, it fails because it cannot compile its GLSL shaders. This is due to them not being appropriately marked as using the [OpenGL core profile](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types).

I tried running the application as administrator and running it in Windows 7 compatibility mode, but unsurprisingly it didn't help. I also tried modifying the DLL files, as they contain the shaders' source by injecting the missing `#version 330 core`, but it only caused the application to immediately crash.

As a last resort, if there is no other solution, I will try to compile it from source, but I'd rather first see it there is an easier solution, as their build system is very unfriendly.

I think the key must be to somehow tell the OpenGL driver that it should consider the shaders to be in core profile, despite them not being marked as such or perhaps somehow emulate a driver from 2011. Alternatively perhaps the DLLs with the shaders' source could be modified in a way that wouldn't corrupt them. I think that the shader source code is in global c-strings, like `const char* vertex = "shader source here"`.

The error message is `error C5052: gl_FragCoord is not accessible in this profile` and seems to happen in the atmosphere shader in `proland-atmo-4_0.dll`.

Comment: Have you tried using older drivers?

Comment: OpenGL support is handled entirely by the display drivers on Windows.